# Getting the domain of an Int with z3

Tags: z3

Is there any way of get the specific domain of an Integer variable with z3 (assuming the variable belong to a finite domain)?

I have the following set of constraints:

```
1 <= X <= 5
2 <= Y <= 8
X + Y == T
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
3 <= T <= 13
```

Or even a simpler case:

```
1 <= X <= 10
5 <= X <= 15
```

I want to get:

```
5 <= X <= 10
```

This seems to be pretty trivial, but I didn't find a way to obtain such an answer with z3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Z3's optimization routines to solve these sorts of constraints. Your first problem can be coded as:

```
(declare-const X Int)
(declare-const Y Int)
(declare-const T Int)
(assert (<= 1 X 5))
(assert (<= 2 Y 8))
(assert (= (+ X Y) T))

(push)
(minimize T)
(check-sat)

(pop)
(maximize T)
(check-sat)
```

To which z3 responds:

```
sat
(objectives
 (T 3)
)
sat
(objectives
 (T 13)
)
```

Which, if you squint right, is saying `3 <= T <= 13`; as you were trying to find out.

You can also use the Python interface to do the same. Your second example can be coded in z3py as follows:

```
from z3 import *

X = Int('X')

s = Optimize()

s.add(1 <= X); s.add(X <= 10)
s.add(5 <= X); s.add(X <= 15)

s.push()
s.minimize(X)
s.check()
print s.model()

s.pop()
s.maximize(X)
s.check()
print s.model()
```

which produces:

```
[X = 5]
[X = 10]
```

indicating `5 <= X <= 10`.

## Getting min/max with one call

If you want to avoid two calls to the solver, then you can use the `box` parameter to optimization, which optimizes the objectives independently:

```
(declare-const X Int)
(declare-const Y Int)
(declare-const T Int)
(assert (<= 1 X 5))
(assert (<= 2 Y 8))
(assert (= (+ X Y) T))
(minimize T)
(maximize T)
(set-option:opt.priority box)
(check-sat)
```

Now, z3 responds:

```
sat
(objectives
 (T 3)
 (T 13)
)
```

which contains the results in the order given, i.e, `3` for minimize and `13` for maximize.

Comment: I also came up with this solution, the problem is that it needs ttwo calls per variable (one to maximize and one to minimize) and I wonder how this will scale one my number of variables grows ... For the moment my set of constraints is rather simple so each call should be easy to the solver, but I had encountered problems in the past when using the optimizer (it can take too long)

Comment: Single call is possible as well, with the `box` parameter. See the edited answer.